# Magento 2: Cron readiness check failed

Tags: magento2, cron

I have below cron on server.

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/magento/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento/var/log/update.cron.log
```

In log file it only says

> Cron readiness check failed